# why Component is not re-rendering after state change. in a react--native function Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, state

this issue i have been facing from several days i an making a function component. i am changing the state by onPress method the console is giving me the same data tha i wanted but it is not re-rendering with the updated data.
this is the snack [link](https://snack.expo.io/@dharmendrasha/scroll-view-search-here)

```
https://snack.expo.io/@dharmendrasha/scroll-view-search-here
```

this is a example code

```
import React, { Componenet, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { ListItem, SearchBar, Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
import TouchableScale from 'react-native-touchable-scale';
import _ from 'lodash'



export default function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

  const updateSearch = search => {
    setSearch(search);
  };

const [list, setList] = useState([{
      name: 'Amy Farha',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice President',
    },
    {
      name: 'Chris Jackson',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice Chairman',
    },
    {
      name: 'Amy Farha',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice President',
    },
    {
      name: 'Chris Jackson',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice Chairman',
    },
    {
      name: 'Amy Farha',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice President',
    },
    {
      name: 'Chris Jackson',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice Chairman',
    },
    {
      name: 'Amy Farha',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice President',
    },
    {
      name: 'Chris Jackson',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice Chairman',
    },
    {
      name: 'Amy Farha',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice President',
    },
    {
      name: 'Chris Jackson',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice Chairman',
    },
    {
      name: 'Amy Farha',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice President',
    },
    {
      name: 'Chris Jackson',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice Chairman',
    },
    {
      name: 'Amy Farha',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice President',
    },
    {
      name: 'Chris Jackson',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice Chairman',
    },
    {
      name: 'Amy Farha',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice President',
    },{
      name: 'Chris Jackson',
      avatar_url:
        'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
      subtitle: 'Vice Chairman',
    },]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <SearchBar
          placeholder="Type Here..."
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            setSearch(text)
              console.log(search)
            }}
          value={search}
        />
        <ScrollView>
        {list.map((l, i) => (
          <ListItem
          Component={TouchableScale}
            key={i}
            leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: l.avatar_url } }}
            title={l.name}
            subtitle={l.subtitle}
            bottomDivider
            rightAvatar={<Icon color="red" raised name="delete" onPress={async () => {
              await console.log(l)
              list.splice(i,1);
              setList(list)
              console.log(list)

            }}/>}
          />
        ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Please do help me i will be very generous

Comment: Are you getting updated list in console.log?

Comment: yes i'm getting the updatated list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your state update doens't cause a re-render is because you are mutating the state while updating and react doesn't think that the state has changed because the reference hasnt updated

You need to clone and update the state

```
  rightAvatar={<Icon color="red" raised name="delete" onPress={async () => {
          await console.log(l)
          const newList = [...list];
          newList.splice(i,1);
          setList(newList)

        }}/>
```

Comment: I have same issue i copy the state and assign in new let then update one of the property then set state(newObj) but it not work!
my code
`onChangeText={(newName) => {
                  const copyObj = editEmployeeSelected;
                  copyObj.name = newName;
                  console.log('copyObj', copyObj);
                  setEditEmployeeSelected(copyObj);
                }}`